# mysql view and replication

Tags: mysql, view, database-replication

I'm asking for input on a tactical question: I am providing a master block of data (5-6 fairly large tables of frequently updated records) to multiple "client" sites that each have their own database serving other purposes.

I was thinking that I could allow the "client" systems to access the master block of data in a couple ways:

1) by simply replicating the data in the master tables into the client DB after each update process runs

2) or possibly by creating the master tables as views in each client database.

Is one tactic more efficient than another, or is there another process that I'm unaware of to serve this need? I realize storage is cheap, so the replication issue isn't probably that bad of a situation, but it's preferable not to have multiple copies to maintain.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing any client access to your master data is dangerous. I would setup MySQL replication. You can configure replication to replicate specific tables with the use of `--replicate-do-table=db_name.tbl_name`

With replication correctly setup, you won't need to worry about running scripts to keep your databases in sync.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: thanks for the input-- I am also a little concerned with the access to the central DB, but I was thinking of making that DB read only to the clients.

Comment: that is typically the purpose of replication slaves - to be read only